# Java process invoked by ProcessBuilder sleeps forever

Tags: java, object, concurrency, process

I'm working on a big system, which I have written entirely in Java. But I'm also at some point communicating with a C program by running it as a process, communicating some input to it through the file system and then waiting for it to finish to read the results from it. For now, I can't do anything but this. There is no time for me to link them via an API or anything like that.

This worked well until I needed to invoke this process twice to get the results. One I make the first invocation, it works just fine. However, for the second invocation the process just hangs! I don't if it is sleeping and waiting for a signal but I don't see why it should do so.

Here is the method to do the invocation:

```
public synchronized boolean processCommand(List command) {
    try { 
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        p.destroy();
    } catch(Exception ex) { return false; } 
    return true; 
}
```

I really do not need to communicate to the stdout or stdin. I just need the process to run and finish its job. But it just hangs when the calling process is waiting for it ONLY the second time I call it! 
My calling code is just simply making the command list and calling this method from another java object.

Both calls to the method processCommand(List command) work fine when the input to the C program is smaller. Would that be some issue with the stdin or stdout?

It's just driving me crazy! Anybody has an insight into this? I appreciate your commend :)

**Update:**

Here is the solution based on what @Gray mentioned:

I just need to drain the InputStream and possibly the ErrorStream:

```
public synchronized boolean processCommand(List command) {
try { 
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process p = pb.start();
    handleStream(p.getInputStream);
    handleStream(p.getErrorStream);
    p.waitFor();
    p.destroy();
} catch(Exception ex) { return false; } 
return true;
```

}

```
public void handleStream(InputStream input) { 
    try { 
        int c; 
        while( (c=input.read())!= -1) { //Anything }
    } catch(Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: Are you sue that the process you are calling has exited?  Maybe it is waiting for user input and you aren't expecting that?

Comment: If there is output from the process, maybe you need to drain the output before you can wait for the process to finish?  Maybe the output is blocking it?

Comment: Is it possible that the C program never exits (e.g. waiting for further input)?  In that case you are still within the `synchronized` method (at `p.waitFor()`) and further calls will be waiting on entering the method

Comment: @Gray the process actually does not exit. The C program I'm calling shows up in ps -a and if I manually kill the process, the Java program proceed, which means the C program is somehow blocked and of course it blocks the Java program too as I use p.waitFor().

Comment: @Gray what do you mean by raining the output? How would I do that?

Comment: @Attila NO. Because I'm able to test the program with the same arguments in the shell. Also, like I said the first call to the same program succeeds with no problems and with exactly the same code.

Comment: @hsnm - what condition is the C program waiting on?  You mentioned you communicate via the file system: do you need to create a file that the program would be waiting on if not present?

Comment: @Attila The C program basically waits for nothing. It accepts parameters to do its job. If the parameters are incorrect or there is any failure in them, it will just stop. So, the C program has no waiting loop. Think of it as if you are invoking ls or ps or something similar. Very simple program.

Comment: One thing I must add but I forgot. Both calls to the method processCommand(List command) work fine when the input to the C program is smaller. Would that be some issue with the stdin or stdout?

Comment: @hsnm - given the info you provided I can't think of any reason why this should be the case.  Few suggestions to try: call a simple program (e.g. ls) instead of the C program you need and see if that exhibits the same issue.  If yes, update the question with a simple, short, compilable program that uses that common program.  Otherwise figure out what is the difference (on a conceptual level) between the common program that works and the C program that does not

Comment: @Attila I edited the question with a similar info. It works with smaller inputs. Actually my C program is not very uncommon. I'm calling glpsol -m source -o output. I understand that I can use the GLPK Java API but since it's a bit complicated I decided to use the glpsol which is a C program that accepts text input (an LP model) and outputs the result. It really doesn't block anything but it hangs for bigger inputs.

Comment: @hsnm - Then it seems there is no issue really: the program you invoke (glpsol) just takes a long time to finish on a larger input.  Do you have the same behavior when invoking from the command line (with the exact same large input)?

Comment: @Attila No, it's a matter of one or two seconds more when invoking the program from the shell. I thought it'd be taking longer for processing but it's not.

Comment: Let me add just one detail: don't drain stdout fully and then switch to draining stderr fully. This will again block if the process fills the stderr buffer. You must drain both in the same loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the solution suggested [here](http://kylecartmell.com/?p=9) (The original link seems to be unavailable; an archived version can be found [here](https://www.cnblogs.com/abnercai/archive/2012/12/27/2836008.html), although the referenced link to the example code still points to the original site...)

> The best strategy for handling this situation is to kick off a thread just prior to calling waitFor that will interrupt the current thread after a suitable time period. TimerTask was designed for precisely this sort of situation, and waitFor is very responsive to interrupts in most cases. [Follow link in original for an example].
>
> [...]
>
> Java 6 API clearly states that failure to promptly “read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.”
>
> [...]
>
> The safe bet for handling this problem today is to explicitly clean up every instance of Process by calling close on each stream made available through Process.getOutputSteam, Process.getInputStream, and Process.getErrorStream, and then call Process.destroy even if the process is already terminated.

Comment: It's a shame that the link is dead.