# Read output from external process

Tags: java, ipc

I am trying to run a .csh script and read it's output into a StringBuffer.
the output sometime returns empty although running the script from console returns some output. the same running flow can sometimes returns output and sometimes not, although nothing is changed in the way the process starts (same script, path , args) and the script isn't changed as well.
I'm not getting any exceptions thrown.
what might cause output now to be read correctly/successfully ?
the code segment is

```
public static String getOutpoutScript(Process p) {
    InputStream outpout = p.getInputStream();
    logger.info("Retrived script output stream");
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outpout));
    String line = "";
    StringBuffer write = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            write.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do something
    }

    return write.toString().trim();

}
```

beside the fact not closing the streams is not good, could this or something else in the code might prevent output from being read correctly under some circumstances ?

thanks,

Comment: Have you debugged to see that p.getInputStream() is always the same, and `output` is assigned correctly?

Comment: Could be the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365402/java-process-invoked-by-processbuilder-sleeps-forever/

Answer (score 0):

If you launch it with ProcessBuilder, you can [combine the error stream into the output stream.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28%29) This way if the program prints to stderr you'll capture this too.  Alternatively you could just read both.  Additionally, you may not want to use readLine, you could be stuck for awhile if the program does not print end of line character at the end.

Comment: the script output is always in the same format (4 lines, 5 words each). so readLine doesn't seems like the problem. i will try reading the error stream. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must replace `p.getInputStream()` with `p.getOutputStream()`

Besides this sometimes processes can block waiting on input, so you must read and write asynchronously - one possible solution is to use different threads - e.g. one thread is reading, other is writing and one that is monitoring the process.

Comment: He could switch between errorstream and inputstream. But switching to outputstream does not make any sense in this context

Comment: Its confusing but InputStream is an InputStream to Java, but the output stream of the program (and visa-versa)

Comment: you need to look at the streams from your point of view and not the process', if you would like to write somewhere (create output) use an output stream, if you would like to read (get input), use input stream

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error, this will write to getErrorStream() by default. If you have a problem, I would ensure you are reading this somewhere.

If the buffer for this stream fills, your program will stop, waiting for you to read it.

A simple way around these issues is to use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).redirectErrorStream(true)